# Program does not return "Correct" even when the right answer is input

Tags: python, random

I started learning Python last month. The following program does not return "Correct" even when the right answer is input:

```py
import random
n1 = random.randint(2,22)
 
import random
n2= random.randint(1,20)

ans=n1+n2

message = input(f"Enter the answer to the question: {n1}+{n2}=")

print(f"Your answer is {message}")

if message == 'ans': 
    print("Correct")

elif message != 'ans':
    print("Wrong")

input()
```

Comment: `ans` in place `'ans'`. `' '` means string not variable

Comment: Also, `ans` is a number, and `message` is a string, so they will never be equal. You need to convert the answer to an integer: `message = int(input(.....))`.

Comment: What tutorial are you learning from that introduces module imports and format strings before explaining what a variable is? Use the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are comparing with literal string `'ans'` but you need to compare with the `ans` object.
2. You need to convert the user input to `int`; by default the type of `input` is str.

```
    import random
    n1 = random.randint(2,22)
    
    n2= random.randint(1,20)
    
    ans=n1+n2
    
    message = int(input(f"Enter the answer to the question: {n1}+{n2}="))
    
    print(f"Your answer is {message}")
    
    if message == ans: 
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
    
    input()
```

Also, you don't need to import the same module twice and you can use `if-else` instead of `if` and `elif` for your case.

Answer (score 0):

the pythonic way

```
import random

n1, n2 = random.randint(2, 22), random.randint(1, 20)
message = int(input(f"Enter the answer to the question: {n1}+{n2}="))

print(f"Your answer : {message}")
print("Correct") if n1 + n2 == message else print("Wrong")
```